# Assigning 2^31 to a float or double

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, floating-point-precision, double-precision

I have to multiply an integer value by 2^31. I have googled it, and it looks like doubles have a range among 2.23e-308 <= |X| <= 1.79e308 when using 64 bits, and a float among 1.18e-38 <= |X| <= 3.40e38.

That's a lot more than what I need. But it doesn't work.

I have this constant value in my header file:

```
static const float SCALE_FACTOR = 2^-31;
```

and if then I just do:

```
float dummy = SCALE_FACTOR;
```

Then, dummy's value is 11.

I don't know if the problem is assigning a constant value like that, but I don't know how else to write it without losing precision.

Any help?

EDIT:Sorry, stupid question. My MatLab background betrayed me and forgot that ^ is not for exponentiation in C++. I have voted to close.

Comment: `^` is the operator for bit-wise exclusive OR. Use `2e-31` to assign a value of 2x10^-31, or `pow(2,-31)` for 2^-31.

Comment: `^` is the bitwise exclusive or operator, not the exponentiation operator.

Comment: Do you want the integer value 2^(31), as the question title and text say, or the fractional value 2^(-31), as the code implies?

Comment: I am rather surprised you got 11 and not -29.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

^ is a bitwise xor operator in C++, not a mathematical exponentiation operator. You have a few alternatives.

1. Because you're storing the constant in an intrinsically lossy format, a `float`, you could just work out the base-10 `e` form literal and use that: perhaps something like `4.6566128730773926e-010` for 2^-31. This is prone to error (I've made one, for example), and isn't necessarily portable between floating point formats.
2. You can set the constant using a constant expression that can be evaluated at compile time, and use an integer literal: either `0x80000000` or `1UL << 31` for 2^31, or `1.0f / 0x80000000` for 2^-31 for example.

You could use a `pow` function of some kind to calculate the value at runtime, of course.

Incidentally, if you're using integers, why not just use a `long long` or other 64bit integral type, instead of a floating point which may well present you with rounding errors? It isn't totally clear from your question whether you are looking at floating point values because you *need* floating point value ranges, or because you are merely worried about overflowing a 32-bit integer value.

Comment: The `e` form is for specifying a decimal number; you'd need 31 decimal places to specify 2^(-31) exactly, and even then I wouldn't trust the compiler to give exactly the required value. Hex literals only work for integers.

Comment: (My comment was based on the code implying that the value should be 2^(-31). If it's actually 2^31, as the question title says, then your answer is fine, although you wouldn't use the `e` form for that value).

Comment: @MikeSeymour if you're dropping the value into a float anyway, why do you need to care about specifying the value precisely? And given the number the OP wants, there's nothing to stop you using a hex literal like this: `const float a = 1.0f / 0x80000000;`, for example.

Comment: @MikeSeymour yeah, I noticed that the original question talks about both 2^31 and 2^-31. Who knows what is actually needed, though!

Comment: If I were dropping the value into an IEEE `float`, which can represent both these values exactly, then I'd definitely want an exact representation. But your suggestion looks good; why not make it an answer?

Comment: I still don't know why C++ doesn't provide a hexadecimal point for literals like 2 to the power of -31. There is a way to do it in C so why not C++. Also could allow mantissa-exponential form of hexadecimal literals like it does with decimal ones eg 2.X-8

Comment: @CashCow: yes, this is one of the absolute worst omissions in the C++11 standard (sufficient to keep me from using C++!)

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
static const float SCALE_FACTOR = 2^-31;
```

the `static` is superfluous (constants have internal linkage by default), the `^` denotes bitwise XOR, the `-` is meaningless (at least if you want to "multiply by 2^31" as stated), and `float` is needlessly a special choice, as opposed to the default floating point type `double` (which e.g. is the type of a floating point literal such as `3.14`).

Also, in C++ reserve shouting ALL UPPERCASE identifiers for macros (the common convention). Using them for constants is a Java-ism. Ironically the Java convention originated with C, where in times past constants had to be expressed as macros.

Instead, therefore write

```
double const scale_factor = 1uL << 31;
```

where

- not explicitly specifying internal linkage (keyword `static`),
- using default floating point type `double` instead of `float`,
- not using ALL UPPERCASE identifier (which should be reserved for macros),
- using left bitshift `<<` to compute power of two, instead of incorrect `^`,
- not adding any meaningless minus sign,
- using type `unsigned long` (specified by `uL`) to be sure to have sufficient range.

Comment: Except that `1uL << 31` gives 2^(31), not 2^(-31).

Comment: @Mike: the question asks for 2^31, both in the title and the text: "I have to multiplicate an integer value by 2^31". Sorry for not pointing out also the meaninglessness of the minus in the OP's code. And thanks for leading my eyes towards that.

Comment: Sorry, I was reading the code rather than the text. If the required value is indeed `2^(31)`, then your answer is just fine.

Comment: The `-` isn't meaningless -- it's incorrect and quite meaningful.

Comment: `Using them for constants is a Java-ism.`/`which should be reserved for macros` That's totally subjective. Plenty of us use caps for compile-time `const`s. Especially as we don't use macros at all.

Comment: @Alf The `static` may be redundant, but I can see a coding guidelines requiring it, for reasons of coherence and readability.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: you can find a little more information about the rationale for the all caps naming convention for macros in Bjarne Stroustrups FAQ, (http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#macro).

Comment: @James: even in this short single line there are a host of potential conflicts with various coding guidelines. you just happened to notice a single such possibility. for example, a coding guideline may require use of `float` rather than my recommended `double`, or using camel case `scaleFactor` rather than underscore based `scale_factor` (or indeed, all caps), or writing the `const` before the type name, or [endless]... there is not necessarily any good rationale for a coding guideline. however, i recommend sutter and alexandrescu's guidelines book, which says: *don't fret the small stuff*

Comment: @Alf Requiring `float` wouldn't be a good idea, but otherwise, yes.  My objection is that you imply that the `static` is wrong, because it's superfluous.  (Or am I reading more into what you said than what you meant?)  There are a number of redundancies that are considered good practice, at least in some circles.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: That's Bjarne's rationale, not mine. There are other people in the world that are not Bjarne, and we all have our ways of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

`^` is an operator for bitwise XOR, not for raising to power. You need `std::pow()`.

Comment: `pow` is fine if either the mantissa or exponent is unknown at compile time, but for constants there's no particular reason not to use a suitable floating point literal.

Comment: @Rook Only that you cannot specify binary floating point literals (or can you?).

Comment: You can in C as of C99, but that has not made it into C++. FWIW, gcc accepts it even in C++ mode: `0x1p-31`

Comment: @ChristianRau that's a good point, and I stand corrected. There are of course _integer_ literals which can do the job fine in this case!

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying by a power of 2 is equivalent to shifting left by that power. To multiply an integer by two to the 31, just shift it:

```
unsigned long value = whatever;
unsigned long value_times_2_to_the_31 = value << 31;
```

There's no need for floating-point math here. But just for completeness, to produce a double value of 2 to the 31:

```
double two_to_the_31 = std::ldexp(1.0, 31);
```

Note that while the result of the shift expression with a signed type would be formally undefined in some situations, that results from overflowing the integer type; using floating-point math instead doesn't eliminate the overflow, it just puts it into a different part of the code.

Comment: the expression `long value_times_2_to_the_31 = value << 31;` has formally UB, but in practice, for a conventional 32-bit two's complement `long` the `value` 1 produces -2147483648 (due to two's complement). you want an `unsigned long` there, as in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13379166/464581). also, no need for the runtime expression, and the header inclusion for that.

Comment: Changed `long` to `unsigned long`.